# inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu) getting StackOverFlowError at this line in ICS Android

Tags: android, stack-overflow

Getting StackOverFlow at this line in some Specific device, i have tested it on MOTOG and it works, but when i am testing it on Micromax Canvas Old it gives:

> StackOverflowError "09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError 09-03 15:18:33.597:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:875) 09-03
>   15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):    at
>   android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:115)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   com.nationalmicromarket.app.BaseActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(BaseActivity.java:44)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2458) 09-03
>   15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:391)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:747)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2566) 09-03
>   15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):    at
>   com.nationalmicromarket.app.fragments.CartFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(CartFragment.java:76)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:1582)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1956)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:391)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:747)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2566) 09-03
>   15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):    at
>   com.nationalmicromarket.app.fragments.CartFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(CartFragment.java:76)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:1582)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1956)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:391)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:747)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2566) 09-03
>   15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):    at
>   com.nationalmicromarket.app.fragments.CartFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(CartFragment.java:76)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:1582)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1956)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293)
>   09-03 15:18:33.597: E/AndroidRuntime(25861):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneW "

Comment: please confirm that what are you using getSuppotMenuInflater or getMenuInflater, also confirm that what do you return in your onCreateoptionMenu method